# unique pointer within a class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, smart-pointers

Let's say we have three class: A, B, C. Both A and B own a pointer to class C. It should never happens that two instance of class A share the same pointer to an object C, but, at the same time, object C is free to be pointed by an instance of class B.

Is there a way to implement this in c++(11)?

======EDIT======

Ok, so let's go more in details. When I create objects C I add their pointers into a container in object B. Objects A may own or not a pointer to C. The important is that no more than one A is pointing to the same C which may actually happen due to user's mistake. Once A is pointing to C a priori it should keep pointing that C for all it's life.

I would have gone for unique pointers, but I need copies of them into the container of B!

Comment: There are lots of different ways.  Do the pointers change?  Are they assigned at construction?  Is a `C` created every time an `A` is created?  What should happen when code tries to assign the same pointer to two `A`s?

Comment: Yes, but it's not trivial.

Comment: `B` could just use a normal pointer. This design is dubious though as it doesn't sound like unique ownership.

Comment: Does an A just own a pointer to a C, or is A the owner of a C and B is just referencing it? That is, is the lifetime of a C bound to the lifetime of an A? Btw, this doesn't sound like anything C++11 smart pointers are supposed to solve.

Comment: I think the best solution to this is for A to hold a unique_ptr to C, and B store a raw pointer to C. However then objects of type B don't "own" the C, so this may not be acceptable.

Comment: Why do you need this? It smells a bit fishy, perhaps there is a better solution to your actual problem than this. What is your original requirement??

Comment: neither A or B are just referencing C as both of they call some C's methods, C is referencing the A who owns it (if any), but ok, now we are going too deep in the problem. I can solve this using raw pointers and implementing some checks, but I was wondering if there was a smart solution to the general case.

Comment: you could have a shared_ptr to C, and a unique pointer to a shared_ptr for instances of A :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want an exception to be thrown if the same pointer is assigned to more than one instance of `A`.

This solution can track used pointers to prevent reassignment.  **It is not thread safe**...you will have to modify this to add synchronization if you need it.

```
class A
{
  // The pointers used by all instances of A
  static std::set<C*> used_ptrs;

  // The pointer used by this instance of A
  C* the_c;

  // Sets the pointer if it is valid
  void set_c( C* c )
  {
    if ( the_c )
      throw std::runtime_error( "C pointer is already set in this A" );

    if ( used_ptrs.count( c ) )
      throw std::runtime_error( "C pointer is already set in another A" );

    the_c = c;
    used_ptrs.insert( c );
  }

  // The pointer is presumed to be unassigned at construction
  A() : the_c(NULL) {}

  // The pointer is removed from the set at destruction
  ~A()
  {
    if( the_c );
      used_ptrs.erase( the_c );
  }

  // Copying A is invalid by your description
  A( const A& ) = delete;
  A& operator= ( const A& ) = delete;
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean, congrats!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a bit of bookkeeping internally in your class, perhaps using a static `unordered_map` member. I have tested the below code to work:

```
using namespace std;

struct C;

struct A
{
  void SetPointerToC(C & aC)
  {
    if ( mAllC.find(&aC) != mAllC.end() )
      assert(false); // multiple instances of A should not point to the same C

    mAllC[&aC] = this;
    mC = &aC;
  }

  ~A()
  {
    mAllC.erase(mC);
  }

private:

  // A is not copyable as to prevent multiple A instances having 
  // mC with the same value
  A(const A &);
  A & operator=(const A &);

  static unordered_map<C*, A*> mAllC;
  C * mC;
};

unordered_map<C*, A*> A::mAllC;

struct C
{

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  A a;    
  A a2;
  C c;
  a.SetPointerToC(c); // works
  a2.SetPointerToC(c); // assert!

  return 0;
}
```